# How to create a long - lived cookie script for my blogger?

Tags: node.js, cookies, makefile, setcookie, samesite

Hello masters I wanted to know how do I create a medium life cookies scrypt for my blogger in HTML.

I have Node.JS installed on my computer. But I have no idea how to start. What format I do create the file in JS? Then do you have to upload the file to a website to implement it in HTML witch   scrypt?

I will be very happy and very grateful if anyone can help me.
I also wanted some material to study on the subject . I have 144 errors on my site and I really needed to resolve.

Meu blogger[https://jogosparaandroidemportugues.blogspot.com/?m=1](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value','domain' { sameSite: 'strict' })

Cookies.get('name') // => 'value'
Cookies.get('domain')
```

```
document.cookie = 'escaped=%u5317'

document.cookie = 'default=%E5%8C%97'

var cookies = Cookies.withConverter({

  read: function (value, name) {

    if (name === 'escaped') {

      return unescape(value)

    }

    // Fall back to default for all other cookies

    return Cookies.converter.read(value, name)

  }

})

cookies.get('escaped') // 北

cookies.get('default') // 北

cookies.get() // { escaped: '北', default: '北' }

and now ? where do i create the api? with node.js itself?
```